# Subsetting pandas dataframe and retain original size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subset a dataframe but want the new dataframe to have same size of original dataframe.
Attaching the input, output and the expected output.

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,4,7,6], [5,6,3,7,0]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])

df_output=pd.DataFrame(df_input.iloc[1:2,:])

df_expected_output=pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,0,0], [2,1,4,7,6], [0,0,0,0,0]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])
```

Please suggest the way forward.

Comment: Hmmm...how can you subset data and yet retain original size? Or do you really mean replace values?

Comment: Yeah replace values with zeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the index after you subset back to the original with `reindex`. This will set all the values for the new rows to `NaN`, which you can replace with 0 via `fillna`. Since `NaN` is a `floa`t type, you can convert everything back to `int` with `astype`.

```
 df_input.iloc[1:2,:].reindex(df_input.index).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,4,7,6], [5,6,3,7,0]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])
output = df_input.iloc[1:2,:]
```

---

You can create a `mask` and use multiplication:

```
m = df.index.isin(output.index)
m[:, None] * df
```

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  2  1  4  7  6
2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

I will using `where` + `between`

```
df_input.where(df_input.index.to_series().between(1,1),other=0)
Out[611]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  2  1  4  7  6
2  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option would be to create DataFrame with zero values and then update it with df_input slice

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df_input.index, columns = df_input.columns)
df_output.update(df_input.iloc[1:2,:])
```